# Замена строки в таблицу MySql из приложения

Tags: php, java, mysql

подскажите пожалуйста как я могу обратиться из андроид программы к базе данных MySql на сервере и заменить данные в таблицы tbl_menu в столбце price на другие .

Comment: Каким способом подключаетесь к базе данных?

Comment: Я сделал правку и указал способ подключения к базе в программе...

Comment: Это метод отправки HTTP запроса, а не подключения к бд

Comment: Так как пользователь БД обычно имеет гораздо больше прав, чем ему было бы необходимо. Например, вы не можете разумными методами ограничить набор получаемых данных. Если у пользователя есть право читать таблицу, то он может читать ее всю. Если ему должна быть доступна только часть строк, вы не сможете ему запретить видеть другие. Кроме того большинство хостингов запрещают доступ к БД снаружи. По этой причине приложениям на устройствах пользователей никогда не дают прямой доступ к БД. Вы должны написать программу на стороне сервера, которая примет данные от клиента и положит их в БД

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку Mike. Так получается что мне надо будет написать программу на стороне сервера и обращятся к программе.... Вот ещё один вопрос , у меня есть админ панель на сервере для обращения к базе MySql  ,могу ли я использовать её в качестве той самой программы на сервере для обращения из андроид приложения...?

Comment: Тут надо писать рест  апи для доступа к бд, тогда можно использовать чттп

Comment: Roman C . не могли бы пример какой нибудь показать...?